# sql server 2008 select same field with different values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select

i need your support

I have a table where data display like following:

```
Id     :   Descrption  : PID
-----------------------------
1         Design         1
2         Log            1
3         Modern         2
4         Log            2
5         Design         2
6         Log            3
```

I want to display `pid` and `description` field where `Description=Design` and `Description=Log`

Comment: Questions on stackoverflow  should show what you have tried and why it didnt work.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Shall we code for you.. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this works for you

```
SELECT
    y1.pid
    ,y1.description
    ,y2.description
FROM
    ytest AS y1
INNER JOIN
    ytest AS y2
ON
    y1.pid = y2.pid
AND y1.description = 'Log'
AND y2.description like 'Design%'
```

Comment: again show another issue actually i need to check all values y1.description='Design' and y1.Description='Log', don't want to use y2.description. please reply ASAP. thanks

Comment: simply reduce the selected columns to `y1.pid` then put it as a subquery into `SELECT * FROM ytest WHERE pid IN (<SUBQUERY>)

Comment: or join ytest a third time...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT T.PID, T.Description 
FROM ytest T 
WHERE
T.Description='Log'
OR
T.Description='Design'
```

Or something along those lines..

Comment: You did change the "YourTable" part to your table name... Right? Failing that you have no data matching your criteria.

That query is fine.

Comment: Should work now, I've edited since I was able to see the table structure.

Comment: no, please check my Q? again, it say when description='Design' and Description='Log' than display records

Comment: Done. My bad, didn't notice my error

Comment: i used following sql query = select pid,Description from ytest as t where t.Description='Design' and t.Description='Log'  = no record display

Comment: tell us what is the name of your table ?

Comment: my table name is ytest

Comment: If that query doesn't work now you have bad data.

Comment: it is required to use and operator not or

Comment: CHANGE IT TO AND THEN. By the way, AND will never bring anything back here. Ever.

Answer (score 0):

selecting records with `Design` or `Log`

```
SELECT pid,
       Description 
FROM ytest
WHERE Description='Design' 
      OR Description='Log'
```

Comment: i used following sql query = select pid,Description from ytest as t where t.Description='Design' and t.Description='Log' = no record display

Comment: could you post the query in sqlfiddle.com

Comment: or tell what should be o/p from above

Comment: tell us what is the name of your table ?

Comment: table name is `table` !!

Comment: query is running perfect but no result display

Comment: discription cannot be 'Design' **AND** 'Log' at the same time...

Comment: @MarcoForberg i know but OP `it is required to use and operator not or – user3004256`

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi `for the same pid` that is... what can not be achieved in a single row as you try it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table.PID, table.Description 
FROM table 
WHERE
table.Description='Design'
AND
table.Description='Log'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all such PID's which have Description both as 'Design' and 'Log' in some row of table say table1 then try as:

```
select t1.pid ,t1.[Description]
from table1 t1
where t1.[Description] in ( 'Design' ,'Log')
and 1= case when t1.[Description] = 'Design' 
            and  exists (select t2.pid 
                        from table1 t2
                        where t2.[Description] = 'Log' 
                        and t1.PID = t2.PID)
            then 1
            when t1.[Description] = 'Log' 
            and  exists (select t2.pid 
                        from table1 t2
                        where t2.[Description] = 'Design' 
                        and t1.PID = t2.PID)
            then 1
      else 0 end ;
```

Comment: thank you prompt response, i have 10 types of designs, so how is possible to use case there

Comment: let me re-phrase it .. you want to select all such pid's where atleast one row exists which have [Description] as either design1 or design2 or .. design10 and also one such row exists which have [Description] as 'Log'?

Comment: i wanto display those pid,descprition when description='Design' and Description='Log' and Description='' and .....

Comment: you want all such pid's which have one row for each of the 10 designs and atleast one row for description 'Log'?

Comment: no dear, i want those records pid, descprition where descrption='Any data' and descrption='Any data' and descrption='Any data' .......